# Allow access to folder only from specific IP Address (or domain) and Port using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to secure access to a PHP page in a folder and only allow access to it from a specific IP Address and domain name but only on a specific port. I have seen a number of questions here but not including the PORT access.

I have added the following in the .htaccess file within the folder.

```
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
 allow from 111.222.333.44:12345
```

However, this seems to be invalid.

What would be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: A firewall is used for this level of control. Do you need to do this at the application level?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement of a specific TCP source port is strange. A TCP source port is almost always choosen randomly by the client - see [epheremal port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port). Also, source ports might change unpredictable if NAT is involved, i.e. typical SoHo router. And such a restriction will limit the client to a single TCP connection. And there will also be some time before the connection can be recreated after it was closed (TIME_WAIT state).

Because of all the drawbacks I think this is not actually want. The requirement might come more from a misunderstanding of how TCP and HTTP work.